# Shiny - Brushed dataset feature not working

Tags: r, shiny

server.ui

```
shinyServer(

function(input, output) {

plot <- eventReactive(input$button, {

if (input$gtype == "Time to Change") {

    dataset = subset(TDU, LBTEST == input$study, drop=FALSE)
    ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x= 'VISITNUM', y = 'LBBLCHGR' , col='factor(ARMAN)')) + 
      geom_line(data = dataset, aes_string(x='VISITNUM',y = 'LBBLCHGR' ,group='SUBJID')) +


    }

    else {

    dataset = subset(TDU, LBTEST == input$study, drop=FALSE)
    ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x = 'ARMCD', y = 'LBBLCHGR', col='factor(VISITNUM)')) + geom_line()

    }

output$plot <- renderPlot({
  plot() 

})

output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
  brushedPoints(dataset, input$plot_brush)
})

})

})
```

I have a corresponding ui.r file which is supposed to display brush_info.  But whenever I try to highlight a point in my graph, I get some error stating that the object dataset doesn't exist?  Why is that?  It clearly exists within a loop.  Why would R make this an obstacle to allowing dataset to become a useable dataframe?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel('Biomarker Comparison'),

fluidRow(column(12, plotOutput('plot', brush = brushOpts(id = "plot_brush"),  dblclick = "plot_dblclick"))),

fixedRow(column(3,selectInput('type', label='Select a Study',choices= c('', 'ADLB_TDU', 'ADLB_TDR', 'ADBM_TDR'))), column(3, uiOutput('selectUI'))),

fluidRow(column(3, radioButtons('gtype', label='Graph Type', choices = list('Dosage to Change', 'Time to Change'))) , column(3, uiOutput('UImeasure')), column(6, h4("Brushed points"),verbatimTextOutput("brush_info"))), 

actionButton('button', 'Draw Graph')

))
```

In simpler terms, how do I access a dataframe, or any object embedded in a loop?

EDIT :

Here is a solution that I came up with.

```
data = reactive({

    dataset = subset(TDU, LBTEST == input$study, drop=FALSE)

}) 



output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
  brushedPoints(data(), input$plot_brush)
})
```

So I put the dataframe into a reactive function, and then I substituted the dataframe name for the function that generates it.  I can't believe that I haven't tried this before.

Comment: What loop are you talking about here? Also, you are only defining `dataset` inside the `eventReactive` for plot. There's no way that variable can be seen in `renderPrint`. Maybe you want a reactive data object? See the example on [this tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/) under "Reactive Expressions"

Comment: So I have to put dataset inside a reactive data object to make it view-able by renderPrint?